# the initialization doesn't wait the async method (xamarin.forms)

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, async-await

I need the others code lines wait the **getUserLocal** finish its job and return the value to they run, mainly the **InitializeComponent();**.
I used **wait** but it seems doesn't work and when the components are initialized, I haven't had the **getUserLocal** result yet...

this is the constructor of my view

```
 public ComoChegarView(double lat, double longi)
    {
        userLocal = new Localizacao();
        getUserLocal();
        Localizacao lojaLocal =  new Localizacao();
        lojaLocal.latitude = lat;
        lojaLocal.longitude = longi;

        InitializeComponent();
     }
```

This is the async task

```
 async Task getUserLocal()
    {
        userLocal =  await Geolocator.GetUserLocationAsync();
    }
```

Does someone know how I can do that?

Comment: See [Async OOP 2: Constructors](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-2-constructors.html).

Comment: See discussion here making async constructors is actively being talked about in csharp. github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/419.

Comment: Well, if you want to keep this design than you may try `Task.Run(async () => await getUserLocal()).Wait();` Your constructor will block while the `async` method will be awaited asynchronously on one of the threads from the pool. It's not the best move but It will work if `GetUserLocationAsync` does not need UI context to work.

Comment: It worked for me 
Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can't call `async` methods from your constructor, that should be more obvious when you can't mark your constructor as `async`, which leads to you not being able to `await` the result of your `async` method.

Comment: :/ then, I need other strategy

Comment: because I need this data before the components initialize

Comment: Yes, you can consider looking into `OnAppearing` event. The event CAN be marked as `async`, there you could `await` your `async` method and the data will be loaded, if I'm not wrong, before `InitializeComponent()`.